# How to connect multiple models in connector (ScopedModel)

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am trying to add fruit item to the cart, but nothing happens**

Once I pressed on the 'add fruit' button nothing happens. It supposes to add fruit items in the cart list. 
I get an error once trying to access the cart screen by pressing on the cart icon in the app bar after the 'add fruit' button was pressed.

[image]

**In this way doesn't work properly:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ScopedModel(
      model: ListModel(),
      child: ScopedModel(
        model: CartModel(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'State Management Scoped Model',
          theme: myAppTheme,
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => MyList(),
            '/cart': (context) => MyCart(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Another way as well:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ScopedModel<ListModel>(
      model: ListModel(),
      child: ScopedModelDescendant<ListModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) => ScopedModel<CartModel>(
          model: CartModel(),
        ),
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'State Management Scoped Model',
          theme: myAppTheme,
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => MyList(),
            '/cart': (context) => MyCart(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

With Provider package everything works fine :)

Comment: Provider just acts like ScopedModel (Inherited Widgets sugar syntax basically), I would say that nowadays would be a better pick over ScopedModel as it has more and official support. So if it is working for you, stick with it. :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, my task is to make work it in both ways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot comment yet.

Try adding the MaterialApp as the direct descendant child of ScopedModel and the use of the ScopedModelDescendant when the changes to the Model actually affect the UI.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ScopedModel<ListModel>(
      model: ListModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         title: 'State Management Scoped Model',
         theme: myAppTheme,
         initialRoute: '/',
         routes: {
           '/': (context) => MyList(),
           '/cart': (context) => MyCart(),
         },
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

and when the property changes lets say in MyCart widget when you list card items

```
... widget tree ...

child: ScopedModelDescendant<ListModel>(
         builder: (context, child, ScopedModel<CartModel> model){
           List cartItems = model.cartItems;
           List<Widget> cartItemWidgets=[];
           cartItems.forEach((cartItemData){
             cartItemWidgets.add(new CartItemWidget(cartItemData));
           });
           return Column(
             children:cartItemWidgets,
           );
         }
       ),

...widget tree...
```

Hope this helps.

Note, ScopedModelDescendant changes every time notifyLsteners() is called.
Doing so on the entire app would be quite expensive I'd think.

Edit:

forgot to add the rebuildOnChange: true property. And also made a mistake.

```
... widget tree ...
//__YOUR__MODEL__: model that changes 
child: ScopedModelDescendant<__YOUR__MODEL__>(
         rebuildOnChange: true, // now the widget rebuilds when notifyListeners(); is called inside the __YOUR__MODEL__
         builder: (context, child,__YOUR__MODEL__ model){
           List cartItems = model.cartItems;
           List<Widget> cartItemWidgets=[];
           cartItems.forEach((cartItemData){
             cartItemWidgets.add(new CartItemWidget(cartItemData));
           });
           return Column(
             children:cartItemWidgets,
           );
         }
       ),

...widget tree...
```

**EDIT 2:**

From going through the git repository I was able to build an example of what you wanted to do. [Here is the link](https://github.com/Laura555-p/scopedmodel) to the GitHub repository. Note: I've initiated an ownership transfer to you. And I'll update the link if you choose to accept. But to also describe the implementation.

You wanted to have two models a ListModel and a CartModel, the list model currently serves as a placeholder for an actual list.

In the CartModel you attached the ListModel.

Whenever you needed the list you got it through the CartModel.

How I changed things?

1. Split class Fruit into a separate file. // objects.dart
2. Turned ListModel into *abstract ShoppingModel* that extends Model
3. Created a singleton SuperModel that extends Model with ShoppingModel and CartModel. Gave it a private constructor and an instance attribute. There will ever only be one instance of this object.
   SuperModel is a mixing it is able to access all the public properties of ShoppingModel and CartModel.
   To avoid editor displayed errors a file was added//analysis_options.yaml that suppresses the error. Note this doesn't affect the program, you can find more information about it on the web.
4. CartModel extends ShoppingModel, now CartModel has access to all the methods of the ShoppingModel it does not have to store the ListModel.
   Use ShoppingModel to add attributes that you might have to use across multiple models.
5. Wrap the app in a ScopeModel, the model attribute is the SuperModel. Since SuperModel is a singleton I used SuperModel.instance, it never has to be instantiated.
6. Added ScopedModelDescendant everywhere where changes might occur, don't forget the rebuildOnChange: true, property.

I've also given you the owner of the repository.

In general, when using multiple models, use inheritance and mixins if they need to exchange attributes. I always used a top abstract Model descendant class that holds all the data that all of my other Models use. Other models extend this class so they are able to get access to these attributes.

But since we need access to their properties across the app and the abstract Model descendant doesn't know their children, we can create a mixin of all the Model in this case SuperModel.
And because we will ever need a single instance make it a Singleton

```
class SuperModel extend Model with Model1, Model2{

  SuperModel._privateConstructor();

  static final SuperModel _instance = SuperModel._privateConstructor();

  static SuperModel get instance {
    return _instance;
  }

}
```

now we can pass the SuperModel to the ScopedModel.

To enable error free mixins add:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true
```

to the end of the pubspec.yaml file

and a new root file analysis_options.yaml:

```
analyzer:
  errors: 
    mixin_inherits_from_not_object: ignore
```

Now this applies to Visual studio code, I don't know if this is handled any differently for Android Studio

Comment: I get an error:  The method 'getById' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getById(0) when pressing on the 'add fruit' button. ///List of fruits in the cart.
  List<Fruit> get fruits => _fruitIds.map((id) => _list.getById(id)).toList(); is provided in the CartModel

Comment: this means _list = null, I'd really have to see more code to know where the problem is. But this mean you're instantiating _list as List _list; and not as List _list=[];
First means the variable was reserved whilst the second one already assigns a List object.

Comment: Thank you, for your help :) Please find the app created with the Provider package https://github.com/Laura555-p/provider_fruits My task to make it work with scoped model as well.

Comment: Ok, just testing it out right now. I'm using an implementation I learned from an Udemy course https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps/ you can find the course on Youtube as well, I'll post the project on GitHub and attache a link to an Edit in the answer

Comment: I haven't used any comments and tried to stick to the source as much as I could but If I saw I'd prefer to change something I did. If you need more help

Comment: Thanks :) now the code looks better, but for some reason didn't accept CartModel and ShoppingModel as a mixin. The class 'CartModel' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object' analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true added.

Comment: Yes, I think I pointed that out on the answer, you have to add analysis_options.yaml file and also I added something else to the pubspec.yaml file at the very end

Comment: And to add an explanation, this was the restriction in Dart 1, now it no longer applies, but the analyser still functions as if it were that's why you have to add:

pubspec.yaml:
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true

and a new root file analysis_options.yaml:
analyzer:
  errors: 
    mixin_inherits_from_not_object: ignore

Comment: Thank you, Hamed,  and thank you, Sar Putnik, with your help the issue was resolved.